# Nagios notifications only for online hosts

Tags: nagios, system-monitoring

At work I have some 30 Linux workstations which share user accounts and data with NIS and NFS. Users are allowed to turn them off if they do not need them. In order to get an overview over the systems I run Nagios which monitors configuration management (Ansible), OS updates, NFS mounts, load and temperature sensors. This works rather well with adjusted warning limits.

One problem is that when a workstation is turned off, I get a bunch of notifications from all the services that are monitored on it. The next day I get another bunch of emails with the recoveries.

I would really like the notifications only to be sent when the host was online. I do want to know when the NFS mounts failed, but not when the host as a whole is turned off.

Admittedly I have only looked into Nagios enough to set up roughly, so in an answer it would already be great to have a few keywords and pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple things.  One - you may not want to have notifications set at the host level as it appears you don't care about that status.  Second, you don't say why the services are alerting. If it is because they enter an unknown state when the host is down, change the notification_options to only alert on, say, critical, warning and recovery (c,w,r)

Comment: Most notifications from turned off hosts are *unknown* and *ok* messages. I have set this to critical and warning only, so I should get a lot less emails. Thanks!